# Data set 'churn' not found in package C50

Tags: r

I am running R version 3.6.3

```
library(C50)
data(churn)
```

results in

> `data set ‘churn’ not found`

Comment: running on `R 3.3.0` with `C50_0.1.1` and can't reproduce this error

Comment: I can reproduce with `R 3.6.2` and C50 v `0.1.3`.

Comment: Try installing the development version of the package `devtools::install_github("topepo/C5.0")`

Comment: I also have the same issue. I tried what @qdread recommended and I still get an issue.

Answer (score 5):

This dataset is available from package *modeldata*:

```
data(mlc_churn)
```